# Problem installing tidyverse: with a Warning in install.packages:installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: package-management

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: recipe for target 'Matrix.so' failed
make: *** [Matrix.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Matrix’
* removing ‘/home/ephrem/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Matrix’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Matrix’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘Matrix’ is not available for package ‘mgcv’
* removing ‘/home/ephrem/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/mgcv’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mgcv’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘mgcv’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/home/ephrem/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ggplot2’ is not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/ephrem/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp85JnYq/downloaded_packages’
Warning in install.packages :
  converting NULL pointer to R NULL
```

---

I’m working on Ubuntu 18 (if it helps) Architecture: i686 CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit Byte Order: Little Endian

```
> sessionInfo() 
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) 
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit) 
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS 
Matrix products: default 
BLAS: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3.10.3 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.so.3.10.3
```

---

Out put of `apt-cache policy r-base-dev`:

```
r-base-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.1.1-1.2004.0
  Version table:
     4.1.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.1-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.0-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.5-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.5-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.1804.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ Packages
     3.6.3-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.6.2-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.6.1-3bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.6.1-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.6.0-2bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.6.0-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.3-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.2-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.1-2bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.1-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.5.0-1bionic 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ Packages
     3.4.4-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
     3.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~esm2 -32768
       -32768 https://esm.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-infra-security/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Did you put them in tmp or is that your default location for downloads? You may want to look at this web site. https://www.fosslinux.com/41739/linux-tmp-directory-everything-you-need-to-know.htm#:~:text=The%20%2Ftmp%20directory%20in%20Linux,applications%20running%20on%20the%20machine.&text=After%20you%20have%20saved%20it,once%20you%20exit%20the%20document.

Comment: How did you installed R 4.1 on 18.04 LTS? Did you follow https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ ? Please add output of `apt-cache policy r-base-dev` to the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually R-packages installation require their compilation, so special dedicated `r-base-dev` package is needed, install it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

Also you can see that errors are self-explanatory, the relevant development libraries for *blas* and *lapack* are missed. To install them and other needed packages use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev libblas-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

And then retry by running

```
R -e install.packages('tidyverse')
```

Comment: I didn't specify any download location. I think it must be the default location wher RStudio downloads. My command was: install.packages("tidyverse")

Comment: Already did those too....and managed to remove some issues. But the unavailable Matrix and mgcv still persist. I have been at it for more than a day!

Comment: y the way, I’m working on Ubuntu 18 (if it helps)

Architecture:        i686
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/atlas/libblas.so.3.10.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/atlas/liblapack.so.3.10.3

Comment: Understood, I'll retry on 32-bit system later, and update answer soon.

Comment: Thank you so much David...it worked!!! I will post your solution!

Comment: Great, so you can accept my answer. Your answer is more like an comment, I would recommend to remove it.